# nginx: trying to enable https results in 'This webpage has a redirect loop'

Tags: nginx, https, cloudflare

In my nginx configuration, if I have the following setup, whenever i go to the site i get 'This webpage has a redirect loop'

```
server {
    listen 80;
    merge_slashes off;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com
    rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent; 
}

server {
     listen 443;
     merge_slashes off;
     server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

     location / { try_files $uri @app; }
       location @app {
          include uwsgi_params;
          uwsgi_pass 0.0.0.0:5002;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
ssl on;
ssl_certificate      /xxx/bundle.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /xxx/server.key;
```

Comment: I am using the Flexible SSL from cloudflare and not provided with those. I get `SSL handshake failed` now.

Comment: now im getting 'This webpage has a redirect loop

Reload'

Comment: Redirects between https/http?